# Firebase upload "user does not have permission", rules are set up correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I'm working on my first ReactJS project and I'm trying to upload image to firebase but whenever I try to upload I get notification in the browser "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/${image.name}'. (storage/unauthorized)" however, I'm logged in using firebase authenticaion. Any help will be appreciated

My firebase settings are

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

function to upload

```
    const handleUpload = () => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
            const progress = Math.round(
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100)
            );
            setProgress(progress);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            alert(error.message);
        },
        () => {
            storage
                .ref("images")
                .child(image.name)
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then(url => {
                    db.collection("posts").add({
                        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                        caption: caption,
                        imageUrl: url,
                        username: username
                    });

                    setProgress(0);
                    setCaption("")
                    setImage(null);

                })
        }
    )
}
```

This is my firebase function

```
    import firebase from 'firebase/compat';
    import 'firebase/compat/auth';
    import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
    import 'firebase/compat/storage';
    const firebaseConfig = { // Have the firebase config here
    apiKey: "XXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXX",
    projectId: "XXX",
    storageBucket: "XXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX",
    appId: "1:XX:X"
};

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Use these for db & auth
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();


export { auth, db, storage };
```

Comment: If you get `storage/unauthorized` then clearly the app does not meet the requirements for accessing the file.  I recommend adding `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser ? firebase.auth().currentUser.uid : "not signed in")` right before you start the upload and checking what that outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your message, I've added console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser ? firebase.auth().currentUser.uid : "not signed in") as you suggest and in return I get my user uid.

Comment: Screenshot of console https://prnt.sc/xFObbKI_3FKe and errors

Answer (score 2):

The rules you posted above are **cloud firestore** rules. Not **firebase storage** rules.

Your firebase storage rules should look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This would permit only authenticated access.

To view firebase storage rules: Storage -> Rules.